# Does Tomcat support TLS v1.3?

Tags: java, ssl, tomcat

Following this older question : [Does Tomcat support TLS v1.2?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9749339/does-tomcat-support-tls-v1-2),
I would like to update it to know whether *TLS 1.3* is supported in recent [versions of Tomcat](https://tomcat.apache.org/whichversion.html).

I didn't find explicit information in Tomcat 9.0 documentation : https://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-9.0-doc/ssl-howto.html

As far as I know, Java 11 seems to include TLS 1.3 support ([release notes](https://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/11-relnote-issues-5012449.html)).

### Notes

- TLS 1.3 support released in Java 11 : [JEP 332](http://openjdk.java.net/jeps/332)
- RFC for TLS 1.3 : [RFC 8446](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc8446)

Comment: Same answer. The TLS version is supported by Java, not by Tomcat.

Comment: It seems to be more subtle than that, as it is possible to use APR/Tomcat Native instead of JSSE.

Comment: So I don't think this is _strictly the same_ answer...

Comment: It is strictly the same answer for the reason I gave above, which also appears several times in the duplicate. And please when we get to TLS 1.4 don't ask the same question yet again.

Comment: Thanks for this constructive answer

Comment: Tomcat supports whatever protocols its underlying environment supports. So if you are using Java 11, you can use TLSv1.3 through JSSE with the Java built-in crypto provider. If you are using OpenSSL through either the APR connector or through the OpenSSL-JSSE provider, then you can use whatever protocols OpenSSL supports, regardless of Java version.

Comment: I've updated the Tomcat 9 documentation to include roughly what I said above.

Comment: Thanks, it should be useful. I was able to find mentions of the protocols though at this page, including TLS 1.3 : https://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-9.0-doc/config/http.html#SSL_Support